# Laravel Increment / Decrement to update display order field

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

After failing with a number of foreach loops, i discovered the Increment/Decrement function, which should make things easier!

I'm trying to update the sort order on a column, refreshing (incrementing or decrementing) the sort counts if they are affected by the item moving positions..

```
public function ImageOrderUpdate (Request $request, $prop, $photo) {

//The photo to edit 
$Photos_Edit = Images::where('property_id', $prop->id)->where('id', $photo)->firstorfail();

$OldPosition = $Photos_Edit->order;     // Old position
$NewPosition = $request->photoorder;    // New position

// Moving down where the fall between positions
if($NewPosition > $OldPosition) {
    Images::where('order','<', $NewPosition)->where('order','>', $OldPosition)->decrement('order');
} 
else {
    Images::where('order','>', $NewPosition)->where('order','<', $OldPosition)->increment('order');
}

// Update the image sort position
$Photos_Edit->order = $NewPosition;

return back();
```

}

Comment: the code looks good, do you have any changes after running?

Comment: Sorry. brain faded...
I was missing the following:
- eloquent ->save(); function at the end.
- Greater than or equal on the update lines...

Those inplace, its doing what i expected